# Logitech k750 Keyboard crashes Wing panel

Tags: wingpanel, keyboard

So I recently purchase my Logitech k750 and I see that now when I boot into the latest Loki version, it doesn't boot into the os and when I decide to hook the keyboard bac after signing in, it makes Wing panel unusable and crashes Wing panel only.

The default drivers weren't working and I installed the Solaar drivers manager and that didn't working either.

I also have a MX Master mouse, if that matters. I was using separate adapters but I unified both devices to use one and its still the same issue.